# Jquery - Resize mask when browser resize?

Tags: jquery, resize, modal-dialog, mask

I am trying to get my modal mask to resize with the browser if someone decides to try...

Right now it just stays at 100% / 100% and looks bad.

Here is a [link](http://trento110.com/site/) <--- click on dinner menu nav - and resize browser window larger then it is currently and you will see what I am talking about.

The jquery is in the source on head area... the first section.

Is this an easy fix? I can make a jfiddle if you would like to make it easyier to trouble shoot.

Thanks,
Muhu

Comment: A jfiddle would certainly make it easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you are using some javascript which sets the absolute window size to the `#mask` div. That is causing your problems - you should use CSS instead.

To override the useless properties set by your javascript, you can use `!important`.

Simply add

```
#mask {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    /* other stuff */
}
```

into your stylesheet and it will work fine.

---

Or, to avoid using the `!important` ugliness, just remove the troublesome piece of code from your script, and the CSS will work even without being `!important`.

```
// THIS IS THE BAD CODE YOU SHALL REMOVE
var maskHeight = $(document).height();
var maskWidth = $(window).width();
$('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});
```